# C# Listbox Bound to Entity "Entity Framework"

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, listbox, linq-to-entities

On my WinForm, I bound my listbox to a Table in `Entity` on EDMX, but when the table data is changed, I tried to call

```
myListBox.DataSource = Entities.table;
myListBox.ResetBindings();
myListBox.Refresh();
```

but nothing happens in `ListBox`. The `Entities.table` object holds the right data though, it just doesn't reflect on the `ListBox`.

Any idea??

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
myListBox.DataSource = null;
myListBox.DataSource = Entities.table
```

There is an optimization in the ListBox, and other data binding classes, that basically will not do an update if the reference assigned to DataSource does not change.  It does not actually do inspection on the contents of the data.  Setting it to null before hand will guarantee that the reference is different.

Comment: Is it the optimal way to achieve that?